# SQL - Executing a `CASE` satement with variable table and column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, variables, case

Hi I am trying to run turn this update query into a tool where I can just define table and column names in a variable.

```
Declare @ExecQuery as nvarchar(max)
Declare @tableName as nvarchar(50)
Declare @Colfrom  as nvarchar(50)
Declare @Colto as nvarchar(50)

Set @TableName = 'upd_employees'
Set @ColFrom = 'EmpCode_Edit'
Set @ColTo = 'EmpName'

--Set @ExecQuery = 'Select '+@Colfrom+','+@Colto+' from '+@TABLENAME

Set @ExecQuery = 'update '+@TABLENAME+' set '+@Colto+' = CASE CHARINDEX('-','+@Colfrom+')
                                     WHEN 0 THEN EmpCode_Edit 
                                     ELSE
                                       CASE CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING('+@Colfrom+',CHARINDEX('-','+@Colfrom+')+1,LEN('+@Colfrom+')-CHARINDEX('-','+@Colfrom+')+1))
                                         WHEN 0 THEN SUBSTRING('+@Colfrom+',1,(CHARINDEX('-','+@Colfrom+')-1))
                                         ELSE SUBSTRING('+@Colfrom+',1,
                                              CHARINDEX('-','+@Colfrom+')+
                                              CHARINDEX('-',SUBSTRING('+@Colfrom+',CHARINDEX('-','+@Colfrom+')+1,LEN('+@Colfrom+')-CHARINDEX('-','+@Colfrom+')+1))-1)
                                       END
                                   END'

EXEC sp_executesql @ExecQuery
```

When I run the query I get this error:

> Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 12 The data types nvarchar and
>   varchar are incompatible in the subtract operator.

I know that you cannot directly save table and column names as variables but when I use the same method `Set @ExecQuery` as a string and then running it using `EXEC sp_executesql @ExecQuery` it works with simple queries (see comment `--Set @ExecQuery = 'Select '+@Colfrom+','+@Colto+' from '+@TABLENAME`) . Why is it not working when I use it in this `CASE` statement?

Comment: It's complaining that you haven't doubled-up the quotes here: `... CHARINDEX('-', ...` and so you're trying to subtract one string from another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at this line:

```
Set @ExecQuery = 'update '+@TABLENAME+' set '+@Colto+' = CASE CHARINDEX('-','+@Colfrom+')
```

You have a literal `-` right between your concatenation statements, not inside your VARCHAR. You need to double single quotes if you want to build Dynamic SQL that contains single quotes.

It should become:

```
Set @ExecQuery = 'update '+@TABLENAME+' set '+@Colto+' = CASE CHARINDEX(''-'','+@Colfrom+')
```

Apply this way of working to the rest of your query.

---

Remarks:

1. Generally you are best to quote table names and column names using [QUOTENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-be/library/ms176114.aspx). That is to allow table names and column names with spaces and other special characters.

```
Set @ExecQuery = 'update '+QUOTENAME(@TABLENAME)+' set '+QUOTENAME(@Colto)+' = CASE CHARINDEX(''-'','+QUOTENAME(@Colfrom)+')
```

2. You are possibly leaving yourself open to SQL Injection attacks if you concatenate strings in a Dynamic SQL statement that way. You are best to replace single quotes with two single quotes in the strings you append:

```
SET @TABLENAME=REPLACE(@TABLENAME,'''','''''');
SET @Colto=REPLACE(@Colto,'''','''''');
```